# Can't create xml using the arguments

Tags: xml, scala

I have a method:

```
def method1(elemName: String, body: Elem) = 
  <someXml>
    <{elemName}>
      body
    </{elemName}>
  </someXml>
```

It complains because of `<{elemName}>` and `body`, where `body` is xml and elemName is a string. Is it made a string to avoid repetition of passing the 2 (open and closing) arguments in xml.

Why, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create `Elem` with name `elemName` manually using method `Elem.apply`:

```
import xml._

val body = <body />
val elemName = "elemName"

val elem =
  Elem(prefix = null,
       label = elemName,
       attributes = Null,
       scope = TopScope,
       minimizeEmpty = true,
       body)
<someXml>{elem}</someXml>
// <someXml>{elem}</someXml>
```

With attributes:

```
val attrs =
  List("k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2").reverse.
    foldLeft(Null: MetaData){ case (as, (k, v)) =>
      new UnprefixedAttribute(k, v, as)
    }

val elem =
  Elem(prefix = null,
       label = elemName,
       attributes = attrs,
       scope = TopScope,
       minimizeEmpty = true,
       body)
<someXml>{elem}</someXml>
// <someXml><elemName k1="v1" k2="v2"><body/></elemName></someXml>
```

With `xmlns`:

```
val elem =
  Elem(prefix = null,
       label = elemName,
       attributes = Null,
       scope = NamespaceBinding(null, "http://myUrl", TopScope),
       minimizeEmpty = true,
       body)
<someXml>{elem}</someXml>
// <someXml><elemName xmlns="http://myUrl"><body/></elemName></someXml>
```

Comment: it complains. Are you sure it is not {Elem(null, elemName, Null, Null, body)} ?

Comment: @Alex: works for me in REPL `2.9.3` and in `2.10.1`.

Comment: Also, I found its definition but I can't figure out how to pass the attributes to it. Could you help me on this one?

Comment: Thanks, but it seems complicated. Isn't there an easy way to add `xmlns="myUrl"` attr?

Comment: @Alex: use `new UnprefixedAttribute("key", "value", Null)` for a single attribute.

Comment: Note that for `xmlns` you should use `scope = NamespaceBinding(null, "http://myUrl", TopScope)`.

Comment: What do you mean by `for xmlns`? If you use `scope = NamespaceBinding(null, "http://myUrl", TopScope)`, shouldn't `xmlns` appear in  one of the attributes as well?

Comment: @Alex: you was correct about `Are you sure it is not {Elem(null, elemName, Null, Null, body)}`, fixed. And no, you should not specify `xmlns` as an attribute.

Comment: I wonder, isn't the type of all expression is `Elem`? It says it is `NodeBuffer`.

Comment: @Alex: it's `Elem` in my `REPL`. `NodeBuffer` is a supertype of `Elem`.